# printing special foreign characters

Tags: php, netbeans, encoding, utf-8, special-characters

I am using php with a netbeans IDE and I want to print some special characters but I can't get anything to work I have tried a few things that have failed please help.

Here is my current code

```
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8');
    mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

    $str = "helloáéíóúñ言文一致";
    print $str; //hello������????

    print iconv(mb_detect_encoding($str), "UTF-8", $str) . "\n";//throws an error


    if(strlen($str)!==strlen(utf8_decode($str))) print $str;               
    else print utf8_encode($str); 
    //prints hello������????

    print "\n" . mb_internal_encoding(); //UTF-8
```

Does utf-8 even support these characters?  I am almost positive that it does.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In NetBeans ensure that the source encoding (of the editor) is okay (probably the case):
Project properties / Sources / Encoding: UTF-8.

Try immediate output:

```
?> helloáéíóúñ言文一致 <?php
```

Ensure you have a full unicode font on the web page for the asian languages.

If you now see good results, you may experiment with PHP.

UTF-8 is a multi-byte encoding of all Unicode characters. Unicode numbers all characters of all languages (mkore or less).

Comment: I am looking for code that will output in the netbeans IDE.  Your suggestion of immediate output shows nothing at all. mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8") ensures that the source encoding is UTF-8